# Understanding why tf-idf gives higher classification accuracy by KNN than BoW and GloVe

Tags: python, feature-extraction, text-classification

I am trying to classify 107 test questions into predefined concepts `(c1, c2, c3, c4)` by KNN classifier in Python. My data is in csv file so it's all in one document. I have split the data to 80% training and 20% testing.

My code works as follows:

1. Pre-process (tokenize, remove stop words, stem)
2. Extract features by either (TF-IDF, BoW, GloVe)
3. Implement KNN classifier on the extracted features

The accuracy results as follows:

```
tf-idf: 95% 
BoW: 62%
GloVe: 57%
```

Why the accuracy is very high with TF-IDF comparing to BoW and GloVe?